# how to use GETDATE() function with xml exist() function

Tags: sql, xml

I have a scenario where i have to use xml exist() function in where clause of the query. where i have to compare date from the xml with the current date. When i try to use GETDATE() function, i get below error.

The argument 1 of the XML data type method "exist" must be a string literal.

Please consider below query for your reference.

```
SELECT 
       TRY_CONVERT(datetime,NULLIF(t.x.value('(./Expire)[1]','varchar(max)'), '')) as expiration_date
FROM VW_Analytics_Base_Facts(nolock) BaseFact
CROSS APPLY BaseFact.Fact.nodes ('/Fact/Grant') t(x)
WHERE TYPE = '/asset/portfolio/option' 
AND BaseFact.Fact.exist('./Expire[(text()[1] cast as xs:date?) le xs:date("' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))+'")]')=1
```

Thanks in advance.

Below is the updated working query.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (XmlCol xml)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
('<option>
            <OptionName>Option 1</OptionName>
            <grant>
                    <GrantName>Grant 1</GrantName>
                            <schedules>
                                            <schedule>
                                                            <scheduleID></scheduleID>
                                                            <scheduleName></scheduleName>
                                                            <scheduleDate>1/1/2018</scheduleDate>
                                                            <scheduleAmount></scheduleAmount>
                                            </schedule>
                                            <schedule>
                                                            <scheduleID></scheduleID>
                                                            <scheduleName></scheduleName>
                                                            <scheduleDate>2/1/2018</scheduleDate>
                                                            <scheduleAmount></scheduleAmount>
                                            </schedule>
                                            <schedule>
                                                            <scheduleID></scheduleID>
                                                            <scheduleName></scheduleName>
                                                            <scheduleDate>3/1/2018</scheduleDate>
                                                            <scheduleAmount></scheduleAmount>
                                            </schedule>
                            </schedules>
            </grant>
            <grant>
                            <GrantName>Grant 2</GrantName>
                            <schedules>
                                            <schedule>
                                                            <scheduleID></scheduleID>
                                                            <scheduleName></scheduleName>
                                                            <scheduleDate>1/1/2019</scheduleDate>
                                                            <scheduleAmount></scheduleAmount>
                                            </schedule>
                                            <schedule>
                                                            <scheduleID></scheduleID>
                                                            <scheduleName></scheduleName>
                                                            <scheduleDate>2/1/2019</scheduleDate>
                                                            <scheduleAmount></scheduleAmount>
                                            </schedule>
                                            <schedule>
                                                            <scheduleID></scheduleID>
                                                            <scheduleName></scheduleName>
                                                            <scheduleDate>3/1/2019</scheduleDate>
                                                            <scheduleAmount></scheduleAmount>
                                            </schedule>
                            </schedules>
            </grant>
        </option>'
)



SELECT e.XmlCol.value('(/option/OptionName)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
        t.x.value('../.././GrantName[1]','varchar(100)') GrantName,
       t.x.value('(./scheduleDate)[1]', 'varchar(100)') scheduleDate
FROM @tbl e
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(date,GETDATE())) dt(today)
    cross apply e.XmlCol.nodes ('/option/grant/schedules/schedule') t(x)
WHERE e.XmlCol.exist('./scheduleDate[(text()[1] cast as xs:date?) le sql:column("dt.today")]')=1
```

i want to filter the record based on schedule date.
This query is a part of view so i cannot declare a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Next time please append a *stand-alone* working sample with DDL, data inserts, your own code and the expected output. This would allow to test a solution.

In this case I have to guess and post untested:

```
SELECT 
       TRY_CONVERT(datetime,NULLIF(t.x.value('(./Expire)[1]','varchar(max)'), '')) as expiration_date
FROM VW_Analytics_Base_Facts(nolock) BaseFact
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(date,GETDATE())) dt(today)
CROSS APPLY BaseFact.Fact.nodes ('/Fact/Grant') t(x)
WHERE TYPE = '/asset/portfolio/option' 
AND BaseFact.Fact.exist('./Expire[(text()[1] cast as xs:date?) le sql:column("dt.today")]')=1;
```

This query will use one more `CROSS APPLY` in order to include the information in the resultset. The function `sql:column()` allows to use a result set's column within `XQuery` without breaking the *must-be-a-literal* rule (use `sql:variable()` to get hands on a declared variable's value).

### UPDATE

Your idea to apply the filter as early as possible is not wrong. This was even better as *predicate* within `.nodes()`. But you have to rely on an implicit cast, something you should not do.

The expression `(text()[1] cast as xs:date?)` will use the system's culture. A value like `1/3/2018` might be taken as 1st of March or as 3rd of January. Therefore I'd suggest to read the value as string and use `CONVERT` with the appropriate style:

Btw: I use two times `CROSS APPLY` with `.nodes()` to avoid *backward navigation* (`../../`)

```
WITH DerivedTable AS
(
    SELECT e.XmlCol.value('(/option/OptionName/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS OptionName
          ,gr.value('(GrantName/text())[1]','varchar(100)') GrantName
          ,sch.value('(scheduleID/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') scheduleID         --use appropriate type, might be "int"
          ,sch.value('(scheduleName/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') scheduleName
          ,CONVERT(DATE,sch.value('(scheduleDate/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)'),110) scheduleDate     --fetch this as varchar, to avoid implicit casts
                                                                                                    --use CONVERT with the appropriate style to get a real date
                                                                                                    --110 is mdy, 103 is dmy
          ,sch.value('(scheduleAmount/text())[1]', 'varchar(100)') scheduleAmount --use appropriate type, might be "decimal(12,4)"
    FROM @tbl e
    CROSS APPLY e.XmlCol.nodes ('/option/grant') A(gr)
    CROSS APPLY A.gr.nodes('schedules/schedule') B(sch)
)
SELECT dt.*
FROM DerivedTable dt
--use a simple WHERE here
```

This will return the XML's content as derived table. Use a simple `WHERE` to filter this derived table.

Comment: Hello sir, i have made changes to the query. The solution you gave didn't work. please have a look.

Comment: @RichiSharma I will have a look on this in about 1 hour... One short question: Is the XML's creation under your control? If yes: It is a very bad idea to store a date in a culture dependant format. Your query will not return the same, if you use `SET DATEFORMAT dmy;` or `SET DATEFORMAT mdy;`. With a value like `13/1/2018` it might fail on another system...

Comment: i don't have control on XML creation. All i have to do is to create a view to create a data set out of it.

Comment: The query is a part of a view. So i cannot use derived query like this. My attempt to apply the filter as early as possible is to minimize the load on the view. Currently since i am parsing the XML, the query is very heavy. That is why i want to filter the records as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the work around which worked for me.

```
SELECT e.XmlCol.value('(/option/OptionName)[1]', 'varchar(100)') OptionName,
    t.x.value('../.././GrantName[1]','varchar(100)') GrantName,
   t.x.value('(./scheduleDate)[1]', 'varchar(100)') scheduleDate
FROM @tbl e
    CROSS APPLY e.XmlCol.nodes ('/option/grant/schedules/schedule') t(x)
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetime,NULLIF(t.x.value('(./scheduleDate)[1]','varchar(max)'), '')) BETWEEN CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: If this works it is okay... I don't know if you checked my updated solution. It follows the same idea (*fetch all values and use a simple `WHERE` to filter the result*), but is more elegant, better to read and avoids some performance killers. If you want to stick with this, you should - at least - add the third parameter to `CONVERT`. Never rely on implicit casts of date values...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions Sir. It really helped.

Comment: If my answer "really helped" it was very nice of you to use your right to vote. Acceptance and votes are the SO-way to say thank you :-D